# Should I address my letter to "Hiring Manager" or the name of the hiring manager?

Tags: job-search, applications, cover-letter, name

I am trying to apply to a company that I have been an intern with. In January when I talk with my old co-workers, they mentioned that the hiring manager is still the same one during my internship.

What would be a professional way to address my cover letter?

I am thinking of addressing it to "Hiring Manager", but I am unsure if I should do it to "name of the hiring manager" instead, in order to make the letter more personal?

Comment: How have you addressed past cover letters? "Hiring Manager" reads a bit robotic IMHO

Comment: Some pointers with the intention of helping you learn your way better here on TWP. Asking "should I" questions is technically off-topic (asking us to make a choice for you), or even fall into the opinion based question... it's best to avoid the "should I" phrasing, and chose other phrasing that makes your goal and objective more evident and explicit... I can see the real (on-topic) question within the current off-topic one, so I will attempt an edit to your post... but bear in mind that some folks may not see such thing and be inclined to Downvote or vote to close

Comment: As a final suggestion, what you are asking rings some bells to me, in the sense of "I bet this has been asked before". I suggest you browse our past questions to see if some of them address your concerns, or perhaps find an exact case for you.

Comment: There, took an edit to your post... feel free to edit it or enhance it if I missed anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the name of the hiring manager, then please use that name. This is the perfect scenario. This sounds more professional, appropriate, and personal too.

In general, if you apply for a new company and don't know the name of the hiring manager, then it is ok to address them in the cover letter as "Dear Hiring Manager".

Comment: But I am not sure whether that person is still here though

Comment: @FaitoDayo you just said that they are still there in your post, your former coworkers confirmed that to you. Mind clarifying this aspect?

Comment: If your former coworkers say that the manager is still working there as you wrote, it is likely that he is the hiring manager.

Comment: she is still in the company by january